# Angular 4: styleUrls not working correctly

Tags: css, typescript, sass, angular2-template, jhipster

I just came across a strange behaviour in Angular 4. I have the following component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'user-wallets',
    templateUrl: './user-wallets.component.html',
    styleUrls: [
        './user-wallets.scss'
    ]
})
export class UserWalletsComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

    <!-- component logic... -->
}
```

In that template I have the following markup:

```
<div class="user-wallets">
    <h2>
        <span jhiTranslate="coinlenderApp.userWallets.home.title">Wallets</span>
    </h2>
    <jhi-alert></jhi-alert>
    <ngb-tabset>
        <ngb-tab *ngFor="let userAccountArr of sourceSystemsUserAccounts">
            <ng-template ngbTabTitle>
               {{ userAccountArr[0].sourceSystem.name }}
            </ng-template>
            <ng-template ngbTabContent>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 charts-col">
                        Charts here
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ng-template>
        </ngb-tab>
    </ngb-tabset>
</div>
```

Now, in the associated stylesheet (SCSS) I have the following styles:

```
.charts-col {
    background: black;
}

.tab-pane {
    float: left;
    min-width: 300px;
    background: black;
}
```

The code is working correctly and the tabs are correctly rendered. There's no error in the console.

Now the strange thing is, that the style for .charts-col is correctly applied, but the styles for .tab-pane is not.

.tab-pane is a generated DOM-object out of .

However, when I put exactly the same styles for .tab-pane in my global.scss, then the styles get applied.

Now my question is: Whey does the styles for .charts-col get applied and not the one for .tab-pane (which is generally working in global.scss, but not in the specific styles for the component)?

Comment: I've added an additional tag for jhipster since it seems you are using this and I think it is relevant to the solution to your problem. I have also had similar issues loading component only css in my jhipster projects and I usually just always change global.scss. A proper solution would be very useful.

Comment: That's correct, I'm using jhipster. What did you add? Is it already committed? And how can I solve the problem :)

Comment: I don't know how to solve it. I'd also like to know the answer. I added an extra tag to your question so it gets more attention from jhipster experts who may be able to help.

Comment: Ahh, that's what you meant by adding an extra tag. I thought you were a developer of jhipster.